# How to gather data from more than two table and put the result in a new one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables...

First table **`Parameter_value_archive`** having columns as:

- `Para_id`,
- `para_value`,
- `created_date`,
- `meter_id`.

Sec table **`meter_primary_master`** having columns as:

- `meter_name`,
- `meter_id`.

third table **`parameter_master`** having columns as:

- `para_name`,
- `para_id`.

I want to collect data from these three tables and put it in a new table name **`Meter_specs`** having columns as:

- `created_date`,
- `meter_id`,
- `meter_name`,
- `para_name`,
- `para_id`,
- `para_value`.

How do  do this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new table having the same table definition of a select clause, use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Meter_specs
AS
SELECT 
  ar.created_date,
  m.meter_id,
  m.meter_name,
  p.para_name,
  p.para_id
FROM Parameter_value_archive ar
INNER JOIN meter_primary_master m ON ar.meter_id = m.meter_id
INNER JOIN parameter_master     p ON p.para_id = ar.para_id = p.para_id;
```

This will make a new table `Meter_specs` with the columns:

- `created_date`,
- `meter_id`,
- `meter_name`,
- `para_name`,
- `para_id`.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e86/1)

Answer (score 0):

DO an insert into select ....
Select should join the three tables, extract the fields you want.  See docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html